# Cookies Not Being Added

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

On the login page I made, this is part of the code behind for the submit button.

```
        Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("userInfo")
        aCookie.Values("user") = Me.usr.Text
        aCookie.Values("last") = Now.ToString()
        If Me.remember.Checked() Then
            aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3650)
        Else
            aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        End If
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
        'Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
        testBox.Text = Response.Cookies("userInfo")("user").ToString()
```

For some reason, when it gets to the last line, it throws an error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

On your first line you call the cookie `userInfo` and on the last line you are referencing a cookie named `loginInfo`, assuming you are trying to access the cookie you just created that's your problem.

Comment: That was a mistake made while chopping up and editing the code to post parts of it here. That issue isn't what's wrong with cookies for me on the project. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 testBox.Text = Response.Cookies("userInfo")("user").ToString()
```

Comment: That was a mistake made while chopping up and editing the code to post parts of it here. That issue isn't what's wrong with cookies for me on the project. Edited and fixed.